# 0/2 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available

Tags: kubernetes

I want to deploy zookeper on native Kubernetes. I tried this deployment chart:

https://bitnami.com/stack/zookeeper/helm

But I get error:

```
0/2 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Provide dynamic storage for your cluster or manually provision persistent volumes that can be claimed.